# SQL how to select rows with count of 2 timestamp entries and 1 filekey

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get filekey and dttmstamps where the count of the dttmstamp+filekey combination = 2

This query:

```
  SELECT [FILEKEY]
  ,(Dateadd(dd,0,Datediff(dd,0,DTTMSTAMP))) as 'DTTMSTAMP'
```

yields:

```
UniqueID   Filekey     DTTMSTAMP
1            1          2014-07-21 00:00:00.000
2            1          2014-07-21 00:00:00.000
3            1          2014-07-24 00:00:00.000
4            1          2014-07-24 00:00:00.000
5            1          2014-07-24 00:00:00.000
6            1          2014-07-24 00:00:00.000
7            1          2014-07-25 00:00:00.000
8            1          2014-07-25 00:00:00.000
```

I would like the results to read as follows:

```
FileKey               DTTMSTAMP
1                        2014-07-21 00:00:00.000
1                        2014-07-25 00:00:00.000
```

and not return 2014-7-24 due to there not being a count of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select FileKey, DTTMSTAMP = (Dateadd(day,0,Datediff(day,0,DTTMSTAMP))) 
from t 
group by FileKey, (Dateadd(day,0,Datediff(day,0,DTTMSTAMP))) 
having count(UniqueID)=2 -- alternately > 1 for all duplicates
```

Comment: OP is specifically asking count=2.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried any option yet?

```
select Filekey,DTTMSTAMP
from <table>
Group by Filekey,DTTMSTAMP
having (count(1)=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your table is named `FILES`, this will result in the set of unique `(FILEKEY, DTTMSTAMP)` pairs where exactly two are present in the table.

```
SELECT [FILES].[FILEKEY]
    , [DATE_ONLY].[DTTMSTAMP]
FROM [FILES]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT (Dateadd(dd, 0, Datediff(dd, 0, [FILES].[DTTMSTAMP]))) AS [DTTMSTAMP]
) AS [DATE_ONLY]
GROUP BY [FILES].[FILEKEY]
    , [DATE_ONLY].[DTTMSTAMP]
HAVING COUNT([DATE_ONLY].[DTTMSTAMP]) = 2;
```

The `CROSS APPLY` is there to allow for easy reference of the date-only part in both `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `SELECT`. Using SqlZim's solution, you will have duplicate transform logic.

The `APPLY` operators were introduced in SQL Server 2005.